# How to make a UIButton border flash when touched

Tags: swift, uibutton

So far the border flashes when touched to match the text, but the border doesn't revert to white after being pressed. I don't know how to make the border flash *while* it's being pressed (initiated in an @IBAction function) I believe it has to do with the button's Touch Up Inside sent event.

```
@IBAction func buttonSearchAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    let myColor : UIColor = UIColor(red: (255/255.0), green: (255/255.0), blue: (255/255.0), alpha: 0.5)
    buttonSearch.layer.borderColor = myColor.CGColor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(highlightBorder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(unhighlightBorder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)unhighlightBorder
{
    myButton.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor greenColor]CGColor];
}


- (void)highlightBorder
{
    myButton.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blueColor]CGColor];
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer - however I'm trying to do this using Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Same solution as above written in Swift:

```
myButton.addTarget(self, action: "unhighlightBorder", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown);

myButton.addTarget(self, action: "highlightBorder", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside);

func unhighlightBorder(){
    myButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor;
}

func highlightBorder(){
    myButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I don't think I explained it well enough - I've edited my question so hopefully you know what I mean.

Comment: You want the border to flash exactly like the text in the button?

Comment: Ok, the effect that is happening to the text is like setting the alpha of the color to 0.5 or something like that. Please tell me what color you want your border to have, and i will supply you the code that shows how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have made progress but not quite there.